# Number of functions (mappings) between sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

**Hello, I would like to ask if somebody has any site or materials that would explain these kinds of exercises.**

**Examples:**
Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11\}$. How many injective mappings $f$ from set $A$ to set $B$ are there, such that $f^{-1}$ ($\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}) = \{1,2,3,4\}$?

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. How many mappings $f$ are there from set $A$ to set $B$ such that  $f(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}) \supseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$ ?

I know how to solve these when they are injective but I dont know how to do it for example surjective or if its just a function (like in second example).
And also what does change in counting them if they are $=$, $\subseteq$ or $\supseteq$.

**I would be thankful for any help/explanation or sites/materials that explain how to solve this.**

Comment: Your second example is missing some symbols...it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: As to the reference question, you can find many such problems on this site.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615641/number-of-bijective-functions-on-a-finite-set), for instance.  That said, it's hard to talk about general methods of solving them, as the possible restrictions one can impose are pretty varied.  As general comments, if "most" functions satisfy the restrictions, then count them without restrictions and remove the bad ones...otherwise, consider adding one restriction at a time.

Comment: oh i didn't notice i missed some, thanks for telling me @lulu

Answer (score 1):

The comments to your question are excellent.

Also, Richard Stanley's twelvefold way [that's where I have first seen it] counts functions between two sets under the constraints of labeled and unlabeled sets and all functions, injective functions, surjective functions etc. This gives a good general framework to such questions. Binomial coefficients, Stirling numbers and falling factorials make an appearence.

[image]

See https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.17

I prefer this representation to that at Wikipedia where group theoretic language is used regarding labeling. It's in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* book (see [https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/)) as well as probably in his lecture notes on his website somewhere.

Comment: thank you, i'll look into it! @kodlu